# Why did I get a teacher badge without answering a question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I've not asked or answered a single question on meta, but I got notified of a teacher badge today.

Is this a bug?

[edit] do the guys need some unit tests? ... hehehe ;)

Comment: You also have a critic badge without any downvotes.

Comment: You're a witch!

Comment: ... Never thought of posting it here, but on ServerFault, I got a Peer Pressure badge, and I don't remember/don't think I have deleted an answer there that met the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your answer to this question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/the-perfect-programmable-christmas-gift/35380#35380

I migrated it, it lived on meta for a while (long enough to generate badges), then I had second thoughts, and migrated it back to SO -- which means it was deleted on meta.

[The perfect *programmable* Christmas Gift!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380354/the-perfect-programmable-christmas-gift)

Comment: oh, make your mind up jeff! ;) Shouldn't the votes migrate with the question? .. not that I've thought that through, just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Bedwyr: Once the badge is awarded, it doesn't get deleted. However, the system will recognize that you "owe" it a badge and thus won't award it to you next time you'd qualify for it. (In these cases, they're single-award badges, so it won't matter much anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you answered a question that was migrated to Meta and then deleted?

Comment: how would I find out the truth!?

Comment: Why, get to 10k rep of course!

Comment: Or ask someone who has 10k rep or is a moderator.

Comment: He is still a witch!

Comment: @acidzombie24 I can live with that. How's being undead working out?